# facebook insights api: difference between items ending in "unique" and "source"

Tags: facebook, api

I have played with Facebook's insights api and I can see I can get a lot of information about a page.

I'm trying to make sense what is the difference between elements named like so:

"page_fan_adds" vs "page_fan_adds_unique" vs "page_fan_adds_source"

**page_fan_adds** - Daily New Likes of your Page (Total Count)

**page_fan_adds_unique** - Daily New Likes of your Page (Unique Users)

**page_fan_adds_source** - Daily This is a breakdown of the number of likes from the most common places where users can like your Page. (Total Count)

I've seen the "description" for each one of them, but it's not very clear on what is the difference.

Many thanks, 
Vladimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to divide the sort of action you are talking about (for example-a like) to three different categories:

1. `page_fan_adds` - The total number of likes your app/page has received.
2. `page_fan_add_unique` - The total number of likes your application received from unique users (this is very common in online advertising analytics-for example, if a visitor from the same IP clicked on a banner twice, only one of the clicks will be considered a unique click. In Facebook, however, I suppose this has something to do with people liking, unliking, and then liking your page/app again-double check on this anyways).
3. `page_fan_adds_source` - You need to understand that a like can happen both in and out of Facebook. An inside like, could be a like while a user is in Facebook and reaches your page/app. An outside like could be obtained by a [one of the many available Social Plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins), for example.

If you could specify exactly what are you currently building, I can try, and give you the best answer possible.

As per the fact you are trying to put all of this in a graph, I would pull all of these three fields, and show them in 2 graphs:

1. Total number of likes and unique likes-this will be a graph with two lines-on the x axis this will be the date, and on the y axis the number of likes. A like this, the user will be able to see the number of total likes in comparison to to the total number of unique likes.
2. Total number of likes by source - this will divide the number of likes between the different sources they came from-outside websites, Facebook, mobile phone apps etc. This will be (for example) the data of the last 30 days-on the y axis there will be the number of likes and on the x axis there will be the source.

Comment: I'm trying to collect all this data, put it in a graph so I can look at it historically and make sense on what I'm looking at.